# merging dataframes join functions

Tags: r, join, dplyr

Trying to merge two dataframes with unequal rows and columns but few common variables between the two dataframes. This is a dummy example. The real data contains over 300 rows and 100 columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)

#modified mtcars data
modified.mtcars.df <- as.tibble(mtcars)
modified.mtcars.df <- rownames_to_column(modified.mtcars.df, var = "motor_cars")
modified.mtcars.df <- modified.mtcars.df %>% select (motor_cars, mpg, cyl, disp)

#delete some rows
modified.mtcars.df <- modified.mtcars.df [1:28, ]

#create empty dataframe
empty.tb <- as.tibble (data.frame (matrix (as.numeric(NA), nrow=nrow(mtcars), ncol = ncol(mtcars))))
colnames (empty.tb) <- colnames (mtcars)
empty.tb <- add_column(empty.tb, motor_cars = as.character(NA), .before = 1)
empty.tb$motor_cars <- rownames(mtcars)
```

> Combine the two dataframes. Output should be similar to mtcars with same number of rows and columns - 32 x 12

`new.mtcars.df <- full_join(empty.tb, modified.mtcars.df)`

> Joining, by = c("motor_cars", "mpg", "cyl", "disp").
>   60 x 12. add rows with motorcars with NA - the last 4 rows of original dataset are also NA

`new.mtcars1.df <- full_join(empty.tb, modified.mtcars.df)`

> 32 x 15. combines the rows but adds the 3 variables with .y. Majority
>   of the values are NA

`new.mtcars2.df <- full_join(modified.mtcars.df, empty.tb, by = "motors_cars")`

> 32 x 15.

`new.mtcars3.df <- full_join(empty.tb, modified.mtcars.df, by = "motors_cars")`

> 32 x 15.

I have tried all combinations of `inner_join`, `anti_join`, `left_join` `semi_join` and `right_join` and also altering modified.mt.cars.df and empty.tb as x and y for each of the above functions.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So, what is your question, please?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  What are you expecting your output to look like?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. Output should be similar to mtcars dataset with 32 rows and 12 columns without any missing/extra rows or columns. I was trying to create an example similar to my problem.

Comment: The join commands do not overwrite the existing data, In this case the join is preserving the mpg, cyl and disp from both data frames.  Once is complete, it is your responsibility to determine which column of data to keep.

Comment: Can you suggest a method where the two tables can be merged, adding the missing rows from empty.tb to modified.mtcars.df so the variable motor_cars has the same number of values, overwriting the NA values in empty.tb with the values in the modified.mtcars.df if present, and keeping the NA for those cells that do not have any values/absent in the modified.mtcars.df. I maybe making this too complicated. I am open to suggestions on how to simplify this whole process. New to R!!